# How to retrieve a portion of a string?

Tags: c, string, printf, stdin

I'm reading in a string of file permissions from stdin and I want to create another string that will hold all characters expect the first from the string the user inputs in stdin.

```
int main(){
  char allPermissions[10];
  char permissions[9];

  scanf("%s", allPermissions);


  for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    char temp = allPermissions[i];
    //printf("%c", temp);
    permissions[i-1] = temp;
  }
  printf("%s\n", permissions);

  return 0;
}
```

If the user inputs: drwx------

Then I expect the program to output: rwx------

But what I get is: rwx------drwx-------

And I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: you don't set the final `\0` of the string

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Ôrel it is copied.

Comment: `char allPermissions[10];` has enough space for **9 characters plus null-terminator**. Since you write 10 characters into it in `scanf` you invoke *undefined behavior*

Comment: @WeatherVane I count 10 characters in `drwx------`- 4 letters and 6 dashes

Comment: Yes sorry deleted, I thought you meant when they are copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through the entire string and copying each element one by one into the destination string works, but it is inefficient and unidiomatic C. You can accomplish this in O(1); after reading the string from `stdin`, just point one after the start of the string:

```
printf("%s\n", allPermissions + 1);
```

This will also work for operations such as copying the string to a new buffer:

```
strcpy(permissions, allPermissions + 1);
```

Do note that an array size of 10 is insufficient for reading a string like 'drwx------' since you also need to take the null terminator into account. In general, I wouldn't use `scanf`-family functions to read from `stdin`; `fgets` is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `null-terminator` character to the end of your character strings. So although `drwx------` is 10 characters to you, it will take 11 chars (including the `\0`) to store it in the memory.

```cpp
int main(){
  char allPermissions[11];
  char permissions[10];

  scanf("%s", allPermissions);

  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    char temp = allPermissions[i];
    //printf("%c", temp);
    permissions[i-1] = temp;
  }
  printf("%s\n", permissions);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GovindParmar Can you clarify what is missing? The OP issue was bcz of not taking the `null terminator` into account in char string.